# Using objects instead of GET

Tags: php, mysql, object, hyperlink

I'm working in PHP to allow users to delete content and I want "delete" to be displayed in text(like a hyperlink) instead of a submit button, however, I don't want to use an actual hyperlink. Think how in most forums when you delete a comment it's generally text saying "delete comment" instead of a submit button.

I'd like to avoid using GET in this case because it's for deleting content. I understand OOP so I don't need an explanation of how it works.

Is there any way to do this with text saying "delete" (not a button) and then use objects to pass it to a function, instead of using a hyperlink to pass values?

Here's what I'm currently using to display the link, however, I use get to retrieve the values, which I would really like to avoid.

```
<td><a href="profile.php?userid='<? echo $request['userid']; ?>'&action=delete"><? echo $request['username']; ?></a></td>

<td><a href="profile.php?userid='.    $requestID['userID'].'">Delete</a></td>
```

Comment: Objects? Sure, use the form object in *javascript*: `<a href="javascript:deleteForm.submit();">delete ...`

Comment: Won't work. Use forms with POST methods instead, or some Javascript to intercept the delete link clicks and convert them into POST requests.

Comment: Use jQuery and AJAX to accomplish this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-request-for-an-example

Comment: If I use forms doesn't that mean it'll use a submit button which is what I'm trying to avoid to begin with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `GET` is to get/retrieve data, you should use `POST` to **POST** updates to the server (i.e. deleting a record).

- You can either use a submit button, and style it to look like a link
  in CSS (best)
- Or you could use an actual hyperlink and use JavaScript/jQuery to submit it for you to the server (not ideal).

I suggest you use the first one if you must use links. However, there's nothing wrong with using `<button>`s:

- Semantically, hyperlinks are supposed to lead the user to a different page, where a button is supposed to make something happen.
- It makes more sense to use a button rather than a link in this case.

Please consider that.

Comment: lol i love the "please consider that", as if a polite way of saying "please dont make it a headache for the other guy" +1.. oh and what @Truth says is ... the truth lol

Comment: I guess I'll just use a submit button and disguise it as text